# Não consigo fazer as variáveis que criei serem reconhecidas ao usar Def

Tags: python

Escrevi o código abaixo que é uma calculadora de triângulos retângulos usando `def` para definir as minhas funções personalizadas.

```
def pedir_base():
    while True:
        try:
            base = float(input('Digite o valor da base do triângulo retângulo: '))
            if base <= 0:
                print(' ')
                print('A base precisa ser um número maior que zero.')
                continue
        except:
            print(' ')
            print('A base precisa ser um número.')
            continue
        break
def pedir_angulo():
        while True:
            try:
                angulo = float(input('Digite o valor do ângulo da base com a hipotenusa: '))
                if angulo < 0 or angulo == 0 or angulo == 90 or angulo > 90:
                    print(' ')
                    print('O ângulo precisa estar entre 0 e 90.')
                    continue
            except:
                print(' ')
                print('O ângulo precisa ser um número.')
                continue
            break
def cálculos(a, b):
        import math
        reto = float(90)
        hipotenusa = base/ math.cos(math.radians(angulo))
        lado = hipotenusa * math.sin(math.radians(angulo))
        LxH = 90 - angulo


        perímetro = hipotenusa + lado + base
        altura = (lado * base)/ hipotenusa
        área = (base * lado)/ 2
        r_insc = (lado + base - hipotenusa)/ 2
        r_circ =  hipotenusa/ 2
def print_dos_valores():

        print(' ')
        print('O valor da base do triângulo é:', round(base, 2), '.')
        print('O valor da hipotenusa do triângulo é:', round(hipotenusa, 2), '.')
        print('O valor do lado perpendicular à base do triângulo é:', round(lado, 2), '.')
        print('Os valores dos ângulos são:', round(reto, 2), ',', round(angulo, 2), ',', round(LxH, 2), '.')
        print(' ')
        print('EXTRA:')
        print('O valor do perímetro é:', round(perímetro, 2), '.')
        print('O valor da altura é:', round(altura, 2), '.')
        print('O valor da área é:', round(área, 2), '.')
        print('O valor do raio do círculo inscrito é:', round(r_insc, 2), '.')
        print('O valor do círculo circunscrito é:', round(r_circ, 2), '.')
        print(' ')
        print(' ')
def final():
        if input('Pressione S caso deseje calcular outro triângulo. Caso deseje fechar a aplicação, pressione qualquer outra tecla.') in ('S', 's'):
            print(' ')
            print(' ')
        if not x:
            print('Fechando a aplicação.')
        return x


while True:
    b = pedir_base()
    a = pedir_angulo()
    c = cálculos(a, b)
    print_dos_valores()
    if not final():
        break
```

O problema é que, ao chegar na parte dos cálculos, ele não reconhece a variável `angulo` criada anteriormente e diz que ela é de tipo NoneType, o que provavelmente também vá acontecer com a variável `base` quando chegar nela. Gostaria de saber o por quê disso estar acontecendo e se eu dei alguma outra bobeira nesse código.

```
def cálculos(a, b):
        import math
        reto = float(90)
        hipotenusa = base/ math.cos(math.radians(angulo))  #Aqui ele não faz a conta e diz que é NoneType
        lado = hipotenusa * math.sin(math.radians(angulo))
        LxH = 90 - angulo


        perímetro = hipotenusa + lado + base
        altura = (lado * base)/ hipotenusa
        área = (base * lado)/ 2
        r_insc = (lado + base - hipotenusa)/ 2
        r_circ =  hipotenusa/ 2
```

Comment: Sua função `calculos` possui 2 parâmetros `a` e `b`. Será que ou você não deveria trocar `a` por `angulo` e `b` por `base` ou, de outra forma, trocar as referências `angulo` e `base` por `a` e `b`? Teo pelo menos mais um problema: sua fnção `final` utiliza uma variável `x` sem defini-la. Estude sobre escopo de variáveis.

Comment: Já tentei fazer as trocas dos nomes das variáveis, mas nada funciona, estou já sem ideias de como poder contornar o problema. Sobre x, acabei de perceber o que você falou e já consertei, obrigado.

Comment: **Escopo Local**:
Uma variável local (criada dentro de uma função) existe apenas dentro da função onde foi declarada.
As variáveis locais são inicializadas a cada nova chamada à função.
Desta forma, não é possível acessar seu valor fora da função onde ela foi declarada. Para que possamos interagir com variáveis locais, passamos parâmetros e retornamos valores nas funções.

Comment: **Escopo Global**:
Uma variável global é declarada (criada) fora das funções e pode ser acessada por todas as funções presentes no módulo onde é definida.
Variáveis globais também podem ser acessadas por outros módulos, caso eles importem o módulo onde a variável foi definida.

Comment: Veja por exemplo sua variável `hipotenusa`, ela é local à função `calculos`e portanto não é conhecida dentro da função `print_dos_valores`.

Comment: não use acentos em nome de variáveis, troque `cálculos` por `calculos` `perímetro` por `petrimetros`, etc

Comment: Pra ver se o ângulo é válido, dá pra fazer `if 0 <= angulo <= 90` (se o ângulo está entre 0 e 90)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu maior problema são as funções. Dê uma olhada em algum conteúdo na internet sobre funções em python. A questão é que você precisa mandar a função retornar algo para poder usar o valor em outro lugar. Segue o exemplo, note que o ângulo está sendo retornado no final da função:

```
def pedir_angulo():
    while True:
        try:
            angulo = float(input('Digite o valor do ângulo da base com a hipotenusa: '))
            if angulo < 0 or angulo == 0 or angulo == 90 or angulo > 90:
                print(' ')
                print('O ângulo precisa estar entre 0 e 90.')
                continue
        except:
            print(' ')
            print('O ângulo precisa ser um número.')
            continue
        break
    return angulo
```

As funções tem escopo local, as variáveis criadas dentro de funções só são acessíveis dentro da própria função, a não ser que você as retorne.

Um exemplo simples da soma de dois números:

```
def valor_1():
    num_1 = int(input("Digite um número a ser somado: "))
    return num_1

def valor_2():
    num_2 = int(input("Digite outro número a ser somado: "))
    return num_2


def soma(numero_1, numero_2):
     resultado = numero_1 + numero_2
     print("O resultado da soma é {}".format(resultado))


valor_1 = valor_1()
valor_2 = valor_2()
soma(valor_1, valor_2)
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.

**Conteúdo**

[Documentação do python](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/)

[Video falando sobre funções em python](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj-_-vP5rnsAhWjB9QKHUTaAwYQtwIwAHoECAQQAg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dezfr9d7wd_k&usg=AOvVaw3Ao19Q3YWFgQmzPEomfv76)